# Must be parseble as Int - Java, Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a class that looks like this:

```
 class SomeConstructorClass {
    
    final Integer lines;
        
    final List<Integer> gameIdList;
    
    SomeConstructorClass(
            Integer lines,
            List<String> gameIdList) {
        Validation.notNull(lines, "lines can not be null");
           
        Validation.notEmpty(gameIdList, "gameIdList can not be empty");
        List<Integer> tempGameIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (String gameId : gameIdList){
            Validation.assertThat(isInt(gameId), "gameId in gameIdList must be parseble as Int");
            tempGameIds.add(Integer.valueOf(gameId));
        }
        this.requestId = requestId;
        this.gameIdList = tempGameIds;
    }
    
    private static boolean isInt(String string){
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(string);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return false;
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

When I am sending gameId in JSON like this:

```
{"gameIds" : [ "3103"}
```

It works fine, but if I put

```
"gameIds" : [ "3103", "random_string"]
```

I get `"gameId in gameIdList must be parseble as Int"` which I should but how can I put so it can take both string and int, should I just not parse it to int?

How can I make this example

```
"gameIds" : [ "3103", "random_string"]
```

work?

Comment: Don't *assert* that it must be an int if it can be something else. Try to parse it and if it fails try the next value in the array instead.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How can I write it in code?

Comment: Do you _really_ send `{"gameIds" : [ "3103"}`? Or did you mean `{"gameIds" : "3103"}`?

Comment: The `gameIdList` should be a `List<String>` instead of `List<Integer>`, then you should remove the `assertThat` line and when you add to the list, you should just add `gameId` and not `Integer.parse(gameId)`

Comment: @user9347049 something like `try { tempGameIds.add(Integer.parseInt(gameId)); } catch (NumberFormatException e) { continue; }`

Comment: I think the array should have a consistent type.  Do you mean it to have ints or strings?  If the entries are different types they should be part of an object, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the assertion that checks if the item is Integer. Use Object as the type for the list:

```
 class SomeConstructorClass {
    
        final Integer lines;
        
        final List<Object> gameIdList;
    
            SomeConstructorClass(
                                  Integer lines,
                                  List<String> gameIdList) {
            Validation.notNull(lines, "lines can not be null");
           
            Validation.notEmpty(gameIdList, "gameIdList can not be empty");
            List<Object> tempGameIds = new ArrayList<Object>();
            for (String gameId : gameIdList){
                // Validation.assertThat(isInt(gameId), "gameId in gameIdList must be parseble as Int") Remove this validation
                tempGameIds.add(isInt(gameId) ? Integer.valueOf(gameId) : gameId);
            }
            this.requestId = requestId;
            this.gameIdList = tempGameIds;
        }
    
        private static boolean isInt(String string){
            try {
                Integer.parseInt(string);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                return false;
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Or better yet create a custom interface and use that to construct your list:

```
public interface GameIdWrapper {
    int doStuff();
}

public class IntGameIdWrapper implements GameIdWrapper {
    private Integer value;

    public IntGameIdWrapper(Object v) {
      value = Integer.valueOf(gameId); 
    }

    public int doStuff() {
      return something;
    }
}

public class StringGameIdWrapper implements GameIdWrapper {
    private String item;

    public StringGameIdWrapper (Object item) {
      list = item.toString(); 
    }

    public int doStuff() {
      return something;
    }
}

public class GameIdFactory {
   public static GameIdWrapper getGameId(String gameId){
      if(gameId == null){
         return null;
      }     
      if(isInt(gameId)){
         return new IntGameIdWrapper(gameId);
      } 
      return new StringGameIdWrapper(gameId);
   }

   private static boolean isInt(String string){
      try {
          Integer.parseInt(string);
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
           return false;
      } catch (NullPointerException e) {
           return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
}

 class SomeConstructorClass {
    
        final Integer lines;
        
        final List<GameIdWrapper> gameIdList;
    
            SomeConstructorClass(
                                  Integer lines,
                                  List<String> gameIdList) {
            Validation.notNull(lines, "lines can not be null");
           
            Validation.notEmpty(gameIdList, "gameIdList can not be empty");
            List<GameIdWrapper> tempGameIds = new ArrayList<GameIdWrapper>();
            GameIdFactory factory = new GameIdFactory();
            for (String gameId : gameIdList){
                tempGameIds.add(factory.getGameId(gameId));
            }
            this.requestId = requestId;
            this.gameIdList = tempGameIds;
        }
    }
```

Comment: With this code you'd fail at the first non-integer value you try to add to tempGameIds.

Comment: Thank you for code example. I have tested it and I think I can leave it as         `List<Integer> tempGameIds = new ArrayList<Integer>()`as well. What do you think? I am talking about first option when removins assertion

Comment: @user9347049, If you remove assertion and use Integer, the code will fail as Matteo mentioned. Either use generics like Object or custom interface or you can skip adding non integerss with if condition such as`if(isInt(gameId)) { tempGameIds.add(Integer.parseInt(gameId)); }`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to validate each element in the `List<String> gameIdList` list.

Update your `SomeConstructorClass` class like this,

```
class SomeConstructorClass {
    final Integer lines;
    final List<Integer> gameIdList;

    SomeConstructorClass(Integer lines, List<String> gameIdList) {
        Validation.notNull(lines, "lines can not be null");
        Validation.notEmpty(gameIdList, "gameIdList can not be empty");
        this.gameIdList = gameIdList.stream().filter(SomeConstructorClass::isInt).map(Integer::parseInt).collect(Collectors.toList());
        this.lines = lines;
    }

    private static boolean isInt(String string){
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(string);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```